# getting dummy value in C++ code rather than expected value

Tags: c++, eclipse, iostream

I am having issue in understanding that why my code is providing me some dummy value.

Can someone help me out that where I am at fault and what is the reason ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class mypair
{
public:
    int a,b;

public:

    int print (int first , int second)
    {
        a = first;
        b = second;
        std::cout<<a <<" hello "<<b;
    }

    int getmax();
};

int mypair ::getmax()
{
    int res;
    res = (a>b)?a:b;
    std::cout<<res;
    return res;
}

int main ()
{
    mypair abc;

    std::cout<<abc.print(5,6);
    std::cout<<abc.getmax();
}
```

Comment: You should turn on your compiler warnings. It would tell you that you don't return anything from `mypair::print()`, but you should be returning an `int`.

Comment: 5 hello 6629564866

Comment: Aside from the answer, you will print max number twice. Try to debug it on your own :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print()` doesn't return any value but it is expected to return an `int`.  This is UB, and your dummy values are caused by this.

In addition, in both `print()` and `getmax()` you send output to `cout`. In the case of `getmax()`,  this output will immediately predede the output of the return value, causing the same number to be displayed twice without any space or separator.

Comment: @john Make the type of print() as `void` not `int`

Comment: @Rietty This is a very reasonable alternative.  But then he can no longer use it as an expression in cout.

Comment: @Rietty thanks a lot but if i make print() as void then i will not be able to get answer as error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: @john indeed!  But I think that Rietty wanted to say that the name of the function, `print()`, suggests that it is called directly to print something without using it in a cout expression.

Comment: @Christophe thanks a lot . I got the point but if i change the name of print() function to something else still provision of dummy value persists. I can resolve this issue if I make constructor instead of print function so I can get exact value but still my confusion is why with existing approach I am having the passing of dummy value issue.

Comment: @john the dummy value is because you do not have a `return` statement. And as you have defined the function to be int, you must return one int and only one.   I confirm that initializing the members in the print() function is a bad idea.  Better rely on a constructor or a setter function to do this (see https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-logical).

Comment: @Christophe Thanks a lot I got it so basically the error was that print() has no return value now I have put return a,b ; and got the results. Thanks a lot for clarifying my concept and also for the link its really useful